# Calling multiple installs from single cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, installation, exe, autodesk

I Know there's a few variations of this question around and I have looked through them to try and find a solution but I'm not having any luck currently. I'm trying to run a series of installs (4) from one command file but it will only run the first install.

I've got a main cmd file with the contents as such:

```
call "Architecture 2015\Install.cmd"
call "Inventor 2015\Inventor2015_Install.cmd"
call "Mechanical 2015\Mechanical2015_Install.cmd"
call "Civil 2015\Civil2015_Install.cmd"
```

Each of those cmd files contains this:

```
"<path>\Setup.exe" /W /q /I Img\Autocad Architecture 2015.ini /language en-us
```

I've tried using

```
start /wait cmd /k call "Architecture 2015\Install.cmd"
```

On each but it still only runs the first. I can't use an exact time because it isn't always consistent over the network. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your four .cmd files just start the program and exit without waiting Setup.exe to finish. This might result in the following scenario:

```
call first cmd ->
  call first setup ->
    exit without waiting setup to finish ->
  main script is notified that first cmd is done ->
call second cmd ->
  start setup -> error (impossible to run two MS install at the same time) ->
  exit ->
call third cmd ->
  same as second cmd ->
call last cmd ->
  same ->
done after one installations and three errors
```

Try using `call "<path>\Setup.exe /W /q /I Img\Autocad Architecture 2015.ini /language en-us"` instead of `"<path>\Setup.exe" /W /q /I Img\Autocad Architecture 2015.ini /language en-us`.